# Link is not working well in Facebook App

Tags: php, smarty, facebook-apps

I am facing a small problem in my Facebook application. when I left single click any link, it will not work, but it will work perfectly when I tried to use right click and open in new window option. Please help me to find out the problem.

This is the URL, please check it http://apps.facebook.com/moviereviewforyou/

The code is:

```
<a href="{$url->reviewMovie($file.fkey)}">
<img src="{$url->img2($file.thumbnail)}"  alt="{$file.ftitle}" width=100 height=100/>
</a>
```

Comment: The page that you are referring to does not allow being shown in a frame. You will need to make sure it is allowed.

Comment: sorry I didn't get u properly :(. Could u plz explain ?

Comment: Also, if there is a correct answer, accept it by clicking on the icon to the left of that answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you don’t have a (valid) SSL certificate – at least that’s the first thing my browser warns me about when I try to access your app (Facebook automatically redirects me to the HTTPS version of it’s page, because I have that option set in my account’s security settings).

And then you have your links href attributes set with a hard-coded `"http://…"` at the beginning, which is also not good when the user uses your app over HTTPS. Just use relative links instead of absolute URLs; or at least have them begin like `"//example.com/…"` (this lets the browser decide which protocol he has to use, based on the protocol used to request the page these links are embedded in).

Answer (score 0):

The page you are referring to has the following in the `<head>` tag:

```
<noscript><meta http-equiv="X-Frame-Options" content="deny" /></noscript>
```

This is what denies showing the page in a frame. Remove this line, or set `content` to `allow` to let it show in the frame.

EDIT:

I noticed that the row I mentioned is in the header of FaceBook itself, not in yours. Are you referring to your page correctly? You shouldn't refer to the facebook page containing your page, but to your page directly.